# Using custom html when running unit test

Tags: dart

I am trying to use a custom HTML page when running a unit test. I am following the instructions outlined on https://github.com/dart-lang/test#running-tests-with-custom-html

My test code (in file test/custom_html_test.dart) looks like

```
@TestOn( 'browser')

import 'dart:html';
import 'package:test/test.dart';

main( ){
  test( "find select", (){
    SelectElement selectAddTimezone = querySelector('#addNewTimezone');
    expect( selectAddTimezone, isNotNull);
  });
}
```

and the html page (in file test/custom_html_test.html) looks like

```
<!doctype html>
<!-- custom_html_test.html -->
<html>
  <head>
   <title>Custom HTML Test</title>
   <link rel="x-dart-test" href="custom_html_test.dart">
   <script src="packages/test/dart.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <select id="selectAddTimezone"></select>
  </body>
</html>
```

I use the following to run the test

> pub run test -p dartium test\custom_html_test.dart

Dartium starts up and loads the page **'test Browser Host'** to run the test - which fails due to the code not finding the selectAddTimezone element, not the custom html I provided.

I am sure I am missing something simple....

Richard

Answer (score 1):

Just use the correct selector

```
SelectElement selectAddTimezone = querySelector('#addNewTimezone');
```

should be

```
SelectElement selectAddTimezone = querySelector('#selectAddTimezone');
```

Comment: du - sorry- I need to talk to a rubber ducky while I code!